# Redirect to a location on same page if contact form errors exist in php

Tags: php, forms, redirect, contact-form

Couldn't find the answer I was looking for on any questions regarding php contact forms so have to ask a new question.

I have a contact form that works fine. When submitted the user is taken to success.php by using `header("Location: success.php");`

The problem lies when errors exist in the contact form. What I have done is use

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"
```

This keeps the user on the same page and displays errors. The problem though is that being a single page website it redirects users to the top of the page and not back down to the contact form where the errors are displayed. How would I use php to scroll down to the contact form so the user knows that their email wasn't sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an anchor in your html-code

```
<a name="jump_here"></a>
```

after this modify you code:

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'#jump_here'; ?>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already use an anchor in the html for the smoothScroll effect. Just wasn't sure how to implement it in the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bookmark.

```
<h2 id="contactform">Contact Form</h2>

<a href="#contactform">Contact Form</a>
```